# Include a bootstrap css file to a spring project jsp file

Tags: java, css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

i want to add bootstrap css files to my spring project.

[image]

this is the jsp file which should include the bootstrap css files.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Login With Database Application</h2>
        <form:form method="post" action="login" modelAttribute="loginuser">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Login ID</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="loginid" id="loginid" path="loginid" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" path="password" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <button class="btn btn-primary"type="submit">Login</button>
            <a href="newuser">New User</a>
        </form:form>
    </body>
```

this is the xml configurartion file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.epic.logindb.controller"></context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userlogin" class="com.epic.logindb.dao.UserLogin"></bean>
    <bean id="loginuser" class="com.epic.logindb.model.LoginUser"></bean>
    <bean id="user" class="com.epic.logindb.model.User"></bean>
    <bean id="edituser" class="com.epic.logindb.model.User"></bean>

</beans>
```

please can you help to integrate bootstrap files to this jsp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Spring MVC application all request are handled by `DispatcherServlet`, You must configure a Resource Handler for handling any static resources like Javascript files or CSS files.

Since you have included the MVC namespace in the spring config xml file you can use the following tag:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="path/resources/" />
```

What you are doing here is mapping all request with `resources` in URI to serve static files inside a folder called resources.

To link CSS in your JSP you can either use JSTL Tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />' />
```

Or  without JSTL but make sure your webapp context is correct:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/basecontext/resources/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: that's work fine :) thank you this <mvc:annotation-driven/> also should add to configurarion xml file at last.thank you a lot